# Run a command line for another logged in user / session on ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this but is it possible to either have a cron, system file, or another logged in user to run a command line or more specifically a script on behalf of another user who's also logged into the same linux system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cron job to execute a script on behalf of another user then you can  do something like this

> 59 10 * * *  bamboo python /usr/share/cleanup.py

In this case the user is `bamboo` who would be executing the python command.

Comment: I need it to execute on a specific session the user is logged into rather than  just "as a user".  it's basically a function I would like for their session to have